# How to create simple array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the shortest way to create this array in Ruby:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It depends on your intention. Do you want to start with 10 and skip by 10 until 100, or do you want to divide between 10 and 100 evenly with 10, etc?

Comment: What have you written? What did searches for this reveal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html) and call [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method on it, like this:

```
(1..10).map{|i| i * 10}
# => [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Or, as suggested by @JörgWMittag, with [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method) method that returns [`Method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html) instance which is converted to proc by `&` notation:

```
(1..10).map(&10.method(:*))
# => [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Answer (score 13):

What about [`Range#step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-step):

```
(10..100).step(10).to_a
#=> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Or [`Numeric#step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step):

```
10.step(100, 10).to_a
#=> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Comment: You second one is nice one to know... for me... :) Now I stopped thinking about any alternative solutions..

Comment: #2 is what I was going to recommend.

Answer (score 2):

This builds an array directly from the constructor.

```
Array.new(10){|i| (i + 1) * 10}
# => [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```