# Why does my code only select year that is equal 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a beginner in programming and have problems with this `if` statement:

```
if (f.year == (10 || 20 || 30 || 40 || 50 || 60 || 70 || 80 || 90 || 100 || 110 || 120)) && (f.rund != true)
```

The first problem is that this code is very complicated. Actually I only want to check if the `f.year` is a round two-digit number.

Next my code does not work correctly. Somehow it only selects the `f.year` that are equal `10`.

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: By the way, your condition is equivalent to `if (f.year == 10) && (f.rund != true)`.

Comment: So now you have the question!

Comment: What did i write `And next my code does not work correctly, somehow it only selects the f.year that are equal 10`

Comment: @EmSta You *"only want to check if the f.year is a round two-digit number"* but your code includes 100, 110 and 120. Please clarify.

Comment: This question is poorly defined. The range of values to be checked is in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because

```
(10 || 20 || 30 || 40 || 50 || 60 || 70 || 80 || 90 || 100 || 110 || 120)
```

expression always evaluates to `10`.

You can solve the problem with, for example:

```
(1..12).map { |el| el * 10 }.include?(f.year)
```

or, as suggested by @AurpRakshit:

```
(1..12).map(&10.method(:*)).include?(f.year)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059294/how-to-create-simple-array-in-ruby) you have more examples of generating this kind of array.

Or, if you really want to check if `f.year` is round two-digit number, you can:

```
(10...100).include?(f.year) && f.year % 1 == 0
```

Comment: I like your one... How is this - `(1..12).map(&10.method(:*))` ?

Comment: @Downvoter: Please give your explanation - I frankly don't know what's wrong with my answer.

Comment: I can understand that the OP, beginning programming, does a literal translation of the pseudocode: 'if year is 10 or 20 or 30 ...', but that same pseudocode is equivalent to 'if year is divisable by 10'.  That should be the solution. Not building an array and doing an include.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Range#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html#method-i-step) or [`Numeric#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step):

```
(10..120).step(10).to_a  #=> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]

10.step(120, 10).to_a    #=> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
```

And call [`Enumerable#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
(10..120).step(10).include? year

10.step(120, 10).include? year
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first point, the code should read:

```
if (f.year == 10 || f.year == 20 || f.year == 30 ...
```

Your expression `f.year == (10 || 20 || 30 ...` doesn't work, because it is evaluated by ruby as follows:

- The brackets force `10 || 20 || 30 ...` to be evaluated first
- The `||` operator returns its left operand if it is true, otherwise it returns its right operand
- Ruby considers anything that isn't `nil` or `false` to be "true", so the expression `10 || 20 || 30 ...` evaluates to `10`
- So your expression boils down to `(f.year == 10) && (f.rund != true)`

Comment: Is there nothing shorter?

Comment: Could the downvoter leave a comment, so I can improve? I think this is an accurate description of why the original code doesn't work as intended?

Comment: This is a good explanation, so I upvoted you. Nevertheless you do not offer a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are already told why your code doesn't work as expected, I'm answering just to suggest to use a mathematical approach here instead of using `include?`, your condition could be written as:

```
if f.year.modulo(10).zero? && f.year.between?(10, 120) && !f.rund
  ...
```

It may be a little less clear but it is much faster.

---

**Update**

The drawback of this solution is that it fails when `f.year` is not a `Numeric` object:

```
nil.modulo(10)
# NoMethodError: ...
```

While:

```
[10].include?(nil)
# => false
```

---

The benchmarck:

```
require 'fruity'

a = (1..10000)

compare do   
  map_include do
    a.each do |i|
      (1..12).map(&10.method(:*)).include?(i)
    end
  end

  step_include do
    a.each do |i|
      (10..120).step(10).include?(i)
    end
  end

  divmod_include do
    a.each do |i|
      q, r = i.divmod(10); (1..12).include?(q) && r.zero?
    end
  end

  math do
    a.each do |i|
      i.modulo(10).zero? && i.between?(10, 120)
    end
  end      
end
```

```
Running each test once. Test will take about 2 seconds.
math is faster than divmod_include by 1.9x ± 0.01
divmod_include is faster than step_include by 9x ± 0.1
step_include is faster than map_include by 3.4x ± 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your question, but the first condition can be written as

```
q, r = f.year.divmod(10); (1..12).include?(q) && r.zero?
```

or

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120].include?(f.year)
```

Comment: I would write it the second way, thus this one gets my upvote.

Comment: Good fit in a single line.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what the OP wants but...

```
require 'fruity'

ARY = (1..1000).to_a

compare do
  test_mod_and_le do
    ARY.each do |i|
      (i % 10 == 0) && (i <= 120)
    end
  end

  test_mod_and_range do
    ARY.each do |i|
      (i % 10 == 0) && ((10..120) === i)
    end
  end

  test_case_when do
    ARY.each do |i|
      case i
      when 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end

  map_include do
    ARY.each do |i|
      (1..12).map(&10.method(:*)).include?(i)
    end
  end

  step_include do
    ARY.each do |i|
      (10..120).step(10).include?(i)
    end
  end

  divmod_include do
    ARY.each do |i|
      q, r = i.divmod(10); (1..12).include?(q) && r.zero?
    end
  end

  math do
    ARY.each do |i|
      i.modulo(10).zero? && i.between?(10, 120)
    end
  end      
end
```

Which outputs:

```
Running each test 32 times. Test will take about 4 seconds.
test_case_when is similar to test_mod_and_le
test_mod_and_le is faster than test_mod_and_range by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
test_mod_and_range is faster than math by 50.0% ± 10.0%
math is faster than divmod_include by 80.0% ± 10.0%
divmod_include is faster than step_include by 5.9x ± 0.1
step_include is faster than map_include by 2.9x ± 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditions do not work this way. All numbers within the brackets, connected with `OR` are evaluated **before** checking the equality with `f.year`.

Most answers here seem overcomplicated. You can use basic math to solve your issue:

```
if year % 10 == 0 && year.to_s.size == 2
   # do stuff
end
```

The modulo operator `%` returns the remainder when dividing by `10` in this example. If the remainder is 0, it's a multiple of 10. You can use any number. Modulo 2 would check whether the number is even.

The second part checks the number of digits. It converts it to a string first with `to_s` and then checks the length of it, basically how many characters are in there. Converting 10 to string results in `'10'` which has 2 characters.

Your question seems a bit unclear. Do you want to include the numbers 100, 110 and 120 like in your code example? Or do you want only two digit numbers like stated in your text?

Comment: A number between 10 and 120 isn't equivalent to a number with 2 digits.

Comment: @Stefan Well, the question states this: "actually i only want to check if the f.year is a round two-digit number", so it seems like the supplied code just doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Good catch, I've overlooked that.